# ConnectionString odbc pwd

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc, connection-string, dsn

I have a problem with the following connection string:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connstr"] = "Dsn=dsn_name; 
Trusted_Connection=yes;Uid=usrName;Pwd=some+Password;";
```

This throws an exception that authentication fails. The problem with that is the '+' sign inside the user password.

Anyone knows how can I escape special characters inside the password?

Thanks!

Comment: Try and use a ConnectionStringBuilder, see http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/09/08/using-the-connectionstringbuilder-class.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The point is, whole thing act as a string,`Dsn=dsn_name; 
Trusted_Connection=yes;Uid=usrName;Pwd=some+Password;` so, `+` act as a character, it does not act as concatenation.

```
string s = String.Format("Dsn={0}; 
Trusted_Connection=yes;Uid={1};Pwd={2}","dsn_name","usrName",some+"Password") ;
```

you can try `String.Format` method to inject string values to appropriate places. I am assunming that `some` is a string variable.

Then, assign s in the code.

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connstr"] =s;
```

Edited:
1.Did you try bringing whole thing to a single line, if you separate it with a ; then there occurs a problem.

2.If this is a authentication failure in the first place, you have to check weather your password user name are correct. you have to add what ever your password after `pwd=`

Comment: yes, it is. But it could also be minus sign or equal or whatever sign

Comment: It still says: Auth failed. 
I did try to bring it all to a single line.